# MVC 5 LogOff form in Area not producing action link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code for creating a form within the layout of an area "Admin". If I don't set the area to blank, the action of the form is set (though it includes the area), but as soon as I set the area to "", or anything else for that matter, the action is blank.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Out <i class="fa fa-sign-out right"></i></a>
}
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<form action="" id="logoutForm" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="blahblah">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Out <i class="fa fa-sign-out right"></i></a>
</form>
```

My routes are setup as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Account",
        "account/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Account", id = "" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "LayoutPartials",
        "partials/{action}",
        new { controller = "Partials" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{*segments}",
        new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", segments = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    "Default",                                              // Route name
    //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    //    new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    //);
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: It likely is a combination of your project structure + your routing configuration.  If you could provide those things, it'll help with providing an answer.  A stab in the dark is that when you're setting the area, it's not matching a route in the route table OR if you have the default route setup; your account controller is not in the admin area.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my route config - what sort of details do you want for project structure?
There is an area called "Admin" which is where the link is being included (as per the question), and the Account controller sits in the root (ie., not in an area).  Happy to provide whatever info will help.

Comment: I think your default route is not doing what you think it should be doing.  I replaced my only route (the one you have commented out) with your default route and I cannot navigate to any page in my application.  I'm not sure what you're goal is with configuring your routes that way, so I don't have any additional suggestions other than to read more about routing here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: That default route is handling the CMS-like behaviour, where everything that comes in other tahn the above-defined routes are put to the Default controller, where the segments are broken up and the appropriate page is displayed from the CMS. So you are correct that it wouldn't work just by copying and pasting it into a new project, because it would indeed send every request to the home page.
The thing is, I have defined a route for /Account/* to be handled correctly already so I'm expecting the action for action "LogOff" in controller "Account" to work.